# How to prevent closing ctools modal window with ESC?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I am using ctools modal window to edit some records with Form API.
How can I prevent closing window with ESC key and the default close button?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar kind of a problem. I had to disable closing modal popup by pressing ESC.
In my case solution was adding unbind for modalEventEscapeCloseHandler for page where I was going to get modal popup:

```
<?php
      drupal_add_js('
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(document).unbind("keydown", modalEventEscapeCloseHandler);
      });
      ', 'inline');
?>
```

Comment: I have checked. It's not disabling close modal popup with button - ESC

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this and it works for me

```
$(function () {
    $('.modal').modal({
        show: true,
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
});
```

If this won't work for you then try adding

```
data-keyboard="false"
```

Something like this:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" data-keyboard="false" 
role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" 
aria-hidden="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialog/Modal box can be disabled from closing as below:

**From escape key**:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  closeOnEscape: false
});
```

Reference: https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeOnEscape

**From close button**:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
    return false;
  }
});
```